# My user and password is correct, but Can't login a flash of black screen and then back to login screen?

Tags: 13.04, login

I have a problem with my account 1 day ago I changed my password and than I forgot my password. I check some solution in many website and I found something as follow:

1. Enter to grub and selected `Advance option for Ubuntu`.
2. Selected `Ubuntu,with Linux\ 3.8.0-11-generic (recovery mode)`
3. Than I selected `root` Drop to root shell prompt
4. Then I write these commands `mount -rw -o remount /`
5. Then `sudo passwd -u` (my account username)
6. Then `passwd` (my account username)
7. Then `vi /etc/lightdm.conf`
8. Then `greater-show-manual-login=true`

And I saved the new configuration but, after restart I was unable to login when I logged in and add my password there was a flash black screen and I was back to the greeting screen? please tell me the solution

Comment: @Rahul I wouldn't try to get rep out of resurrecting a 2 years old question.

Comment: @rahul your feed?

Answer (score 0):

Seems it tried to find you home directory when the monitor flash black screen.

Using  `Ctrl+Alt+F1` then login with your username and password if you found error can't find home directory you need to set home directory by using following command.

`sudo usermod -d /home/user user` replace user with your username

But if there is your home already, please check disk space. Low space is also the root cause of this kind of issue.